# Laravel Spark not logging in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

The spark registration page shows up fine. I fill out the form, submit, and there is a new entry in the database.

Calling the function to get the current user :

```
$router->get('/user/current', 'Laravel\Spark\Http\Controllers\UserController@current');
```

With the controller ...

```
 /**
 * Get the current user of the appliation.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function current()
{
    return response()->json(Auth::check());
}
```

This `Auth::check()` returns false. And `Auth::user()` in this place returns nothing.

Logging in via the spark login page as that user has the same results.

However,  going back to the login or registration pages reroutes me as if I am logged in. I can also poke around the spark settings pages and add new teams, etc.

Why does spark think I am logged in and why doesn't it actually log me in?

Comment: Might want to add a little more code thanjust the 2 functions you call..

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I wish that I knew what code to add. Spark is installed and running properly. For some reason it is not logging in a user. Is it supposed to be like this or is something wrong?

Comment: Do not post answer in your question. I've moved it to the answer section. You can propose improvement if you like.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that the app has been using gulp to serve and build it. Now that the app is up and running and being served through the php artisan serve command, it is no longer accessible via the URL `192.168.10.10/...` and it now called through `localhost:8000/...`

The problem was that calling the `192...` did not produce an error so I didn't think to check that.

[@Joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40111116/3)